# ASP.NET MVC 5 mask download link to Amazon S3 resource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 to host multiple files on my ASP.NET MVC web application, but in order to allow a download, I'm sharing with the end user the direct S3 url, so I have many security issues, like if the user shares this link, it would perform download directly without requiring to sign up on my site, or that they know on which Amazon S3 Bucket their files are hosted. What options do I have in order to mask this download link so the user should authenticate first on the site?

Answer (score 0):

If you share the S3 link to your hosted file and you have the bucket set to public access, you can't really control much.

You would need to create a proxy endpoint that handles your authentication, then streams the S3 hosted file to your response.

Comment: I want to change the bucket access level too. Is there and example of how to do this? I automatically thought of a 301 Redirect but I think I could still present flaws